# Is there a workaround to create a URI with an underscore in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uri

I'm trying to create a URI which contains an underscore (it's pointing to a UNC path) like so:

```
hplLink.NavigateUri = new Uri(String.Format("{0}\\{1}", selectedFolder.LinkTitle, selectedFolder.FolderPath), false);
```

Unfortuantely this chokes up with the following:

```
Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
```

I need to essentially create a hyperlink in a WPF application and I am unable to do so on paths containing an underscore.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your URI look like?

Comment: \\wmerff008\shared\test_folder

Comment: What is the content of `selectedFolder.LinkTitle` and what is the content of `selectedFolder.FolderPath` ?

Comment: @dotNET, sure but i want to know what String.Format produces, which is the reason why the Uri constructor fails. (I consider slashp's response as telling us what folder he *wants* to get an Uri for...)

Comment: Thanks guys but as it turns out it was bad data from our SQL DB.  I'm gonna delete this question.